# What happens if I overwrite an ImmutableHashSet while enumerating it?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, immutability

I'm trying to debunk immutable collections here. My point of attack is the classical pub-sub event broker where we maintain an `ImmutableHashSet<Subscription>` of subscriptions.

A subscribe operation would then do

```
var s = new Subscription(this, subscriber);
subscriptions = subscriptions.Add(s);
```

and a publish operation would do something like

```
foreach (var s in subscriptions)
  s.Subscriber.OnNext(args);
```

However, let's suppose hypothetically that while the publish operation is happening, someone subscribes, the variable `subscriptions` get replaced. Will the `foreach` loop work correctly, or would it be utterly broken? (And if so, what can one do to fix this?) Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `subscriptions` variable is only read at the *start* of the loop. Remember that `foreach` is translating your code into something like:

```
using (var iterator = subscriptions.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        var s = iterator.Current;
        s.Subscriber.OnNext(args);
    }
}
```

So basically, changing the value of the `subscriptions` variable after you've called `GetEnumerator()` won't affect the rest of the behaviour at all - it'll only affect it *next* time. (Assuming the relevant memory barriers are in place, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to worry about multi-thread access to `subscriptions` provided that the _only_ operation being performed on it is an overwrite? This can be assumed to be atomic, right?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: It's atomic, but that's not the same as volatility. You'll never see an invalid reference - but you might not see the most recently written value, either. Consider using `Interlocked`, or a lock.

Comment: would it make sense to use `ImmutableInterlocked` instead?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: Haven't seen that. If it's basically a wrapper which allows you to atomically change a reference, then yes :) (I haven't used the new immutable collections personally yet.)